# How to get data from excel sheet in html/css page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, asp.net

I have one HTML template http://blog-mission-log.space/edit.html. This page is for one state Arkansas of US and I need to make pages for other 50 states with the same design. This template is for a survey of US states. The design of page would be same but the content for all states will be different. The data is stored in one excel sheet. And I need to get the data from that excel sheet in the specific page of a particular state. Here is excel sheet data screenshot http://prntscr.com/jz0e77

Is there any way that I can create the other 50 pages by populating data from that excel sheet with any code in Javascript/Jquery or any other platform? Or any other solution for this?

Comment: This can be via PHP as well as other server side languages. You'll want to read the Excel file using an Excel library, or save the Excel file as a CSV file and read it directly with `fgetcsv()`. You'll parse the fields based on State and fill out your HTML with the field values.

Comment: @Mr. Glass, thank you for your response. This solution is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could start learning node.js (it allows you to script/build apps in javascript). Then you can use a module like node-xlsx  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx to parse the Excel files and transform it into html data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This solution is helpful.